# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error use clarification

Tags: ios, core-data, persistent-storage

I apologize if this information exists somewhere but I've not been able to find it.

I seek clarification of Apple's doc for **NSPersistentStoreCoordinator**.  The doc for **addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error** says:

> **Parameters**
>
> *storeType*
> A string constant (such as NSSQLiteStoreType) that specifies the store type—see “Store Types” for possible values.
>
> *configuration*
> The name of a configuration in the receiver's managed object model that will be used by the new store. The configuration can be nil, in which case no other configurations are allowed.
>
> *storeURL*
> The file location of the persistent store.
>
> *options*
> A dictionary containing key-value pairs that specify whether the store should be read-only, and whether (for an XML store) the XML file should be validated against the DTD before it is read. For key definitions, see “Store Options” and “Migration Options”. This value may be nil.
>
> *error*
> If a new store cannot be created, upon return contains an instance of NSError that describes the problem
>
> **Return Value**
> The newly-created store or, if an error occurs, nil.

Observing the behavior, it appears that addPersistentStoreWithType creates the physical database file at *storeURL* if doesn't exist.  The newly created db file or an existing db file at *storeURL* is then associated with the "new" persistent store that was "added".

This was not obvious to me reading the docs.  Do I understand this correctly?  Any further information is appreciated!

Comment: Which bit wasn't clear? The on-disk file or the in-memory instance of the store?

Comment: @Wain, I did not read into this documentation that an existing persistent store would be opened.  The return value says newly-created store, so I assumed it expects to create the persistent store file.

Comment: The return value refers to the persistent store coordinator, not the on-disk file.

Comment: @Wain,I see your interpretation.  The fact that it both attaches to an existing physical file and creating a missing physical file is not what I expected.  Thanks.